# Cannot load sqlsrv

Tags: php, wamp, sqlsrv

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, if not, please tell me where. I need to connect a php script running on wamp with an MSSQL server. I downloaded and installed the [Microsoft Drivers for PHP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) and added the following lines in php.ini:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

The weird part is that the extension is shown as loaded when I look for it in the wamp menu, and not found in phpinfo();

[image]

[image]

(thread safety is enabled, hence I use the ts version)

**EDIT**

I solved it, wrote the solution below. But, I still cannot get it to work on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. Same problem, extension is loaded in the menu, but not on the wamp homepage and phpinfo();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success, finally.

1. First, I downloaded an [unofficial x64 version of sqlsrv](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=669EE24817961774%21720) (good job Microsoft on not labeling and leaving only 32bit versions -_-)
2. Second, I downloaded and installed the [SQL Native Client x64](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239648&clcid=0x409).

Hope this helps if anyone else has the same problem.

**ЕDIT**

I still have the same problem on the same wamp installation on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio? I remember that solved one of my problems. Unfortunately I still have other ones, which I have just posted a question for. I will be trying the x64 version and see if things work. Looks like it is version 3.0, so I suppose ODBC 11 won't work with it and one would need to use native client

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this was a problem we went around by using a service on the server for database communication, but I will try as soon as I get the chance.